# Why does my ssl certificate not work on port 4443?

Tags: ssl, server, certificate, webrtc

I'm setting up an openvidu demo on a server with Ubuntu as shown in this tutorial:
https://openvidu.io/docs/deployment/deploying-ubuntu/

But I'm having problems when making a video call because it marks me an error with my certificate on port 4443

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk70L.png)

I checked my certificate and it seems that everything is fine but I do not understand what is happening.

[Certificate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pplTc.png)

I am new working with servers and I am not sure what is happening. Do I have to do some other configuration to recognize port 4443?
Does anyone know what I can do to solve this error?

Comment: I can help you out, but for that, I need to know about the Domain name or website address. – Sandy P. Chaudhry 32 mins ago

Comment: Thanks @Sandy P. Chaudhry My domain is https://topmeddr.com

Comment: @SandyP.Chaudhry Can you help me?